# Conservation of momentum in electrodynamics and force on the northern hemisphere of a uniformly charged sphere

Tags: classical-electrodynamics

In chapter eight of his book "Introduction to Electrodynamics", Griffiths gives the following example:

"Calculate the net force on the 'northern' hemisphere of a uniformly charged solid sphere of radius R and charge Q."

The force then comes out as $F=\frac{1}{4\pi \epsilon_0}\frac{3Q^2}{16R^2}$.

My question: How is it possible that a uniformly charges hemisphere experiences a net force that is not equal to zero? According to this example, a uniformly charged hemisphere would continuously be accelerated, thus violating principles like conservation of energy and momentum.

Comment: You have misunderstood the question. The total force which the N hemisphere exerts on itself is zero. The question is asking for the force which one hemisphere S exerts on the other hemisphere N of a complete sphere. This force is not zero.

Answer (score 1):

You are true in the sense that the charges feel force for all the moments.However here in this problem the charges are sort of embedded in a spherical configuration.That is they are fixed in space.The task is to to calculate force on one of the hemisphere due the other hemisphere. If the charges were free to move then of course they would in a the direction of net force on it due to all the other charges.

In the case when the charges are free the conservation of energy is obeyed in following way. When the charges where put together to form a spherical distribution some works were done against there mutual force of repulsion which is stored in the configuration as self energy.When they are free to move this energy is converted to kinetic energy of the charges.Also the Coulomb force decreases as $r^{-2}$ so at large distance they feel essentially no force.

Conservation of momentum is also obeyed as the initial momentum of the whole system is zero and when allowed to move momentum of charges which are diametrically opposite cancels each other giving net momentum zero.